# How do you create a two variable list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I know the usual way in Python of creating a 2d list is by making a list of lists and accessing an element with `foo[3][2]`. However, when performing some operations needed for AES, it would be helpful to use `foo[-1][2]`, which would be a column of the data (`-1` is every value).

Would it be possible to set up a 2d list using the format `foo[3, 2]` free from object-oriented classes, or not? Side note: the only time I've ever seen this is in the PILLOW Image library for Python, however it was used in a class, and I don't know how to isolate just what I want.

Comment: try `foo[:][2]` You will get the data from 3rd column.

Comment: Your right, thanks.

Comment: Enjoy learning. :)

Comment: @RajanChauhan I'm lost. Isn't `foo[:][2]` not the same as `foo[2]` ?

getting a column instead of a row would be more something like
`list(zip(*foo))[2]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic 'all values' built-in for lists ... but:

You can write things like `bar(foo[*])` as `map(bar, foo)` or `[bar(x) for x in foo]`.

For example, `foo[*][2]` can be `[x[2] for x in foo]`.

Another option when trying to get columns is to transpose the results (though consider using numpy et al. at this point).  You can do this with `list(zip(*foo))`, as mentioned by @gelonida.

If you are willing to use classes or helpers then you have many other options to get the syntactic sugar you desire.

Comment: my main question was wanting a format like foo[x, y]

Comment: @TyStaszak you can do `x = {(1,2):3}; assert x[1,2] == 3` if you want.